# Problem with Approximatetime policy

Tags: laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to use the Approximate time policy. I'm able to run the code provide as a tutorial here. (http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) But when I use classes I'm getting a lot of error.

```
typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix, sensor_msgs::Imu, sensor_msgs::LaserScan> MySyncPolicy;

class myclass
{
public:            
myclass();   
ros::NodeHandle nh;
void callback(const sensor_msgs::NavSatFixConstPtr& , const sensor_msgs::ImuConstPtr& , const sensor_msgs::LaserScanConstPtr& );


private:
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix> *sub_fix;
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Imu> *sub_imu;
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> *sub_laserscan;
  Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> *sync;
};

myclass::myclass()
{

sub_fix = new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix>(nh, "kitti_player/oxts/gps", 100);
sub_imu = new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Imu>(nh, "kitti_player/oxts/imu", 100);
sub_laserscan = new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>(nh, "scan", 100);
 
   sync = new message_filters::sync::ApproximateTime<MySyncPolicy> (*sub_fix, *sub_imu, *sub_laserscan,1000);
   sync->registerCallback(boost::bind(&myclass::callback, _1, _2, _3));
}


void myclass::callback(const sensor_msgs::NavSatFixConstPtr& gps, const sensor_msgs::ImuConstPtr& imu, const sensor_msgs::LaserScanConstPtr& scan)
{
 std::cout<<" "<< gps->header.stamp <<"   " << scan->header.stamp << "\n" ;
}
```

Can someone please suggest a way to write this properly.

Thanks & Regards
Sriram

PS:: some of the errors

```
/home/student/students/sriram/test_ws/src/test_sub/src/test_sub.cpp: In constructor ‘myclass::myclass()’:
/home/student/students/sriram/test_ws/src/test_sub/src/test_sub.cpp:47:15: error: expected type-specifier
    sync = new message_filters::sync::ApproximateTime<MySyncPolicy> (*sub_fix, *sub_imu, *sub_laserscan,1000);
               ^
/home/student/students/sriram/test_ws/src/test_sub/src/test_sub.cpp:47:15: error: expected ‘;’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/student/students/sriram/test_ws/src/test_sub/src/test_sub.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::_bi::result_traits<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (myclass::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > >&)>’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:15:48:   required from ‘class boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (myclass::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list3<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3> > >’
/home/student/students/sriram/test_ws/src/test_sub/src/test_sub.cpp:48:69:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:37: error: ‘void (myclass::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
     typedef typename F::result_type type;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244196/problem-with-approximatetime-policy/) by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2016-09-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When passing a class to boost::bind, it needs an instance too. Try this.

```
sync->registerCallback(boost::bind(&myclass::callback, this, _1, _2, _3));
```

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2016-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on 2016-09-22**:
hi,
thanks. i tried what you suggested and it think the previous error is solved. Now I have a diiferent one.

```
In constructor ‘myclass::myclass()’:
sub.cpp:45:15:error: expected type-specifier sync = new message_filters::sync::ApproximateTime<MySyncPolicy> (*sub_fix, *sub_imu, *sub_laserscan, 1000);
```

**Comment by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on 2016-09-22**:
I think my mistake is the way I'm using this line

```
sync = new message_filters::sync::ApproximateTime<MySyncPolicy> (*sub_fix, *sub_imu, *sub_laserscan,1000);
```

I used the example provided here [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/190082/simple-approx-time-sync-example-errors/) and i works

**Comment by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on 2016-09-22**:
And changing it to this made it work

```
 sync = new Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> (MySyncPolicy(10), *sub_fix, *sub_imu, *sub_laserscan);
```